# C# code to access author name in DOCX returning error on GetXDocument. 'does not contain a definition for 'GetXDocument'

Tags: c#, openxml, docx

I am trying to debug C# code to access the 'author' attribute in DOCX files. The method below is being passed a variable 'savePath' which represents the DOCX file. VS doesn't like `GetXDocument` and returns the error:

> `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.MainDocumentPart` does not contain a
>   definition for `GetXDocument` and no extension method `GetXDocument`.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
    private void changeRevAuthor(string savePath)
    { 
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        XNamespace w = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main";
        WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(savePath, false);

        XDocument mainDocumentXDoc = wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.GetXDocument();

        var nodes = mainDocumentXDoc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Attributes(w + "author").Count() > 0).ToList();
        foreach (var node in nodes)
        {
            string authorname = node.Attribute(w + "author").Value;
            if (!result.Contains(authorname))
                result.Add(authorname);
        }
        wordDocument.Package.Close();
        return result;

    }
```

Comment: Right, I [don't see it either](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.maindocumentpart_members.aspx).  Maybe you like the Document property better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetXDocument` is part of `OpenXML Powertools` libary. Nuget it and add it to your solution and you will be good.

Once you add the `OpenXmlPowerTools` package from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenXmlPowerTools/) - import the following namespace

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using OpenXmlPowerTools;
```

Comment: Thank you Flowerking. I've added NuGet and installed and added OpenXmlPowerTools and this has removed the initial error. However, it seems this script was built with NET 4.0 and I am now receiving an error that OpenXmlPowerTools cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved by first adding OpenXmlPowerTools and 2nd changing the Target NET Framework version of the project to 4.5 under Project > (Project Name) Properties > Application

Thank you!!

Comment: Then you should mark Flowering's answer as correct.